# Facing these errors while doing "create-react-app"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, babeljs

The error I'm getting is like this:

```
vaibhav@Knighthood MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Coding NInja/tool (master)
$ npm start

> tool@0.1.0 start C:\Users\vaibhav\Desktop\Coding NInja\tool
> react-scripts start


There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.42.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\vaibhav\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.44.1)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\Users\vaibhav\node_modules\webpack is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tool@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tool@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vaibhav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-01T10_23_38_476Z-debug.log
```

---

I have tried to fix the dependency tree by the suggested steps:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the
   package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

But I'm still facing the same error.

---

My system configurations are:

- Node -v : 12.18.3
- npm -v : 6.14.8
- OS : Windows 10 pro v2004 H1 x64

Comment: What is your question? These messages are warnings not errors to begin with. Also related to different things. Please read [ask]. And be more specific with the question.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Whenever I'm executing "npm start" to run the server, it throws the error and probably all errors are coming because of these warnings. I've updated the question. Please go through it once more !!

Comment: " it throws the error " which error are you talking about? None of what you have posted is an error nor it is related to the error you haven't posted so far. :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have uploaded the wrong error message before. Now I have updated it. I hope now you'll understand. @YuryTarabanko

Comment: this could be a cache issue. try running `npm cache verify`, then deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, and then running `npm install` followed by `npm start`

Comment: I have tried these commands many times but nothing happened. @lanxion

Comment: update the package.json file to the question

Comment: How ?? @AakashRajni

Comment: add the text in your package.json to the question

Comment: Can you explain, what to do add there? @AakashRajni

Comment: Are you there ?? @AakashRajni

Comment: i need to see your package.json file to correct the error.please attach file to the question